ViewModelProvider - .Incomptible type with Fragment
My Android program used to be working, i used Android studio to get the bottom navigation View Activity. it works. After i run in the actual mobile phone device, it is not working any more, it complains like below:
incompatible types: HomeFragment cannot be converted to ViewModelProviderImpl
new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
the HomeViewModel.java was generated by Andorid studio, after i selected to create the bottom navigation View Activity.
package com.abc.myapplication.ui.home;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is home fragment");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}

My HomeFragment.java shows below, was also generated by Android Studio.
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        // new code
        HomeViewModel= new ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication())).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textHome;
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
        return root;
    }

Would anyone please advise and give me the sample codes as possible?

Can you include the imports for your fragment class also?

I had a similar issue while using Java instead of Kotlin with compiledSDK version set to 34 in build.gradle(app). Setting compiledSDK version to 33 actually solves this problem. You will have to downgrade some of the library in build.gradle.

thank you so much. you save me a lot of time

Will an application with compiledSDK 33 be allowed into Google Play?

Please check the publishing guidelines, currently in my opinion it is allowed.

Rolling back androidx.lifecycle to version 2.6.1 helped me:
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'


Using Java, rolling back to 2.7.0 was enough for me.

try this:
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
